# Is there a way to implicitly get instance of an object

Tags: scala, shapeless, type-level-computation, frameless

We want to create an encoder for arbitrary `Enumerations` with [frameless](https://github.com/typelevel/frameless) which
is basically creating a bidirectional mapping from an arbitrary `Enumeration` to `Byte`. Currently our less than optimal solution is to give evidence on all of our Enumeration instances so the deserializer can pick it up and call `apply` on that instance, a method that creates an `Enumeration` from a `Byte`. We want to find a way without defining these implicit values, and rather have them automatically picked up from the `E` type. As far as we know object types are in one-to-one correspondence to a single instance, so we hope there's a mechanism to do this.

For example, the following works

```
import frameless._

object Color extends Enumeration {
  type Color = Value
  val Red, Green, Blue = Value
}
object State extends Enumeration {
  type State = Value
  val Running, Stopped, Finished = Value
}

implicit val colorEvidence = Color // we want to spare these lines
implicit val stateEvidence = State // we want to spare these lines

implicit def enumToByteInjection[E <: Enumeration](implicit e: E): 
  Injection[E#Value, Byte] = Injection(_.id.toByte, e.apply(_))
```

Comment: You don't have the declarations of the enumerations under your control? Otherwise you could simply declare the enumerations as `implicit object`s and thereby spare you the pain of defining a separate implicit method for every enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1 (reflection)**

This here compiles and runs when compiled with `scalac 2.12.4`:

```
object Color extends Enumeration {
  type Color = Value
  val Red, Green, Blue = Value
}
object State extends Enumeration {
  type State = Value
  val Running, Stopped, Finished = Value
}

/** Dummy replacement with similar signature */
class Injection[A, B]()


import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

object ItDoesNotWorkInReplObjectsMustBeTopLevel {

  implicit def enumToByteInjection[E <: Enumeration](implicit tt: TypeTag[E]): Injection[E#Value, Byte] = {
    val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
    val classLoaderMirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val moduleSymbol = ru.typeOf[E].termSymbol.asModule
    val moduleMirror = classLoaderMirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
    val companionObject = moduleMirror.instance.asInstanceOf[E]

    println(s"/* 1 */ Materialize companion object $companionObject out of nothing!")
              /* 2 */ ???
              /* 3 */ // profit!
  }

  /** A function that requires implicit `Injection` */
  def testNeedsInjection[E <: Enumeration](implicit inj: Injection[E#Value, Byte]): Unit = 
    println("replace ??? above to continue here")


  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    /** Test whether an implicit injection is constructed */
    testNeedsInjection[Color.type] // compiles (crashes, as expected, but compiles)

  }
}
```

It of course crashes because of the missing implementation at `???`, but this comes *after* the implicit companion object is summoned into existence.

Gotchas:

- Doesn't work when run as script
- Doesn't work in REPL (needs objects to be top-level)
- Make sure you are using the right ClassLoader, supplying something like `classOf[Unit].classLoader` leads to `NoSuchClassException`s.
- Requires `TypeTag`s for the enums (shouldn't be a problem when used with *concrete* enums on top-level, but could become a problem if the method is supposed to be buried deep in a library but still have "access to the surface": then you would have to pull `TypeTag`s through every method to the surface).

---

**Solution 2 (implicit objects)**

If you have all enums under your control, then you could simply declare the enumeration objects themselves `implicit`. The following compiles just nicely, all implicits are inserted as expected:

```
implicit object Color extends Enumeration {
  type Color = Value
  val Red, Green, Blue = Value
}
implicit object State extends Enumeration {
  type State = Value
  val Running, Stopped, Finished = Value
}

/** Dummy replacement with similar signature */
class Injection[A, B]()

implicit def enumToByteInjection[E <: Enumeration](implicit e: E): Injection[E#Value, Byte] = ???

/** A function that requires implicit `Injection` */
def needsInjection[E <: Enumeration](implicit inj: Injection[E#Value, Byte]): Unit = ???

/** Test whether an implicit injection is constructed */
needsInjection[Color.type] // compiles (crashes, as expected, but compiles)
```

Comment: We will choose the second solution because we want to avoid runtime reflection.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 3 (shapeless magic)**

We can also use Shapeless `Witness`es to summon the singleton value for our Enumeration type. Shapeless uses compile time reflection and code generation to create an instance for the given type.

```
import shapeless._

implicit def enumToByteInjection[E <: Enumeration](implicit w: Witness.Aux[E]):
  Injection[E#Value, Byte] = Injection(_.id.toByte, w.value.apply(_))
```